# Can't view bash history for SSH sessions

Tags: ssh, sudo, bash-history

When logging in as a user via ssh, then sudo su - to become root I can't see the history of commands run.

I've tried cat /root/.bash_history  running the "history" command, etc.  I only see the results of root's history.  Additionally, if I run the history command or cat /home/user/.bash_history  I will see the sudo su- command but nothing that happens after that.

We have multiple people logging in and then switching to root via sudo su -  via ssh, but there seems to be no log of what commands are run after this happens.

Comment: Once you do `sudo su` you are not you any more. You are root. So history you should do `sudo cat /root/.bash_history`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output (from the `sudo su -` shell) of commands `echo "$-"` and `shopt histappend`

Comment: Yes, I did a cat on root and user .bash_history when I cat the root .bash_history, I see commands that I ran explicitly logged in as root when I was setting up the machine, but not the stuff I'm doing as root in the SSH sessions.

Answer (score -1):

As @user68186 mentioned, when you change the logged-in user the `.bash_history` file changes with it, you need to search in the home directory of the logged-in user. In this case, it is `/root`

Comment: I looked at root's .bash_history under /root/.bash_history  and the commands aren't appending to the history file.